# how to set base path for all imports in react

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

In a create-react-app cli project, using configs below to set all import paths to `src` as base url

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
..
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

all I want to use import statments like this:

```
import { PanelHeader } from '@/components/panel';
```

instead of this:

```
import { PanelHeader } from '../../../components/panel';
```

Comment: try adding a path like this: `"@/*": ["./the-path-that-you-want"]`

Answer (score 0):

By checking [Absolute Imports](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports) on CRA you can see two things:

(1) Setting `baseUrl` to `src`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

(2) Using `components/..` when importing a component from folder called `components` (subfolder of `src` folder)

Example — `import Button from 'components/Button';`

So, get rid of `@/` part.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add it to your webpack config and jsconfig files.

Install the following packages,

`npm install customize-cra react-app-rewired`

Then create a `config-overrides.js` in root project and add the following,

```
const { override, addWebpackAlias } = require('customize-cra');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = override(
  addWebpackAlias({
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
  })
);
```

Add the following to your jsconfig.json,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```

You will have to use `react-app-rewired` to start your project or add it to your `package.json` scripts,

`npx react-app-rewired start`
or

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
...
```